# Can I always replace 2nd conditional with were to + verb

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tenses, conditionals

I'm wondering if I can, for most of the times use -> **were to + verb** to start an if sentece for example:

1. If I were to have money, I would buy a car

   *instead of:*

   If I had money I would buy a car
2. If I were to build a house I would have my own property

   *instead of*

   If I built a house I would have my own property
3. If I were to have a pen I would take notes

   *instead of*

   If I had a pen I would take notes

Comment: We're all familiar with the construction *If I were [noun]* (as in *If I were you, I'd kill myself* and [*If I were a rich man...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22If+I+were+a+rich+man%22)),  but when there's an infinitive involved I'm only really comfortable with it if the contemplated hypothetical situation is *something I'm actively considering doing*. Which would include *If I were to go out to dinner with you, I'd expect you to pay your half of the bill*. I certainly can't be doing with *If I were to have money I'd take you out to dinner and you wouldn't have to pay a thing*.

Comment: The usual expressions are: have money, have a car and build a  house. There is no reason to make them awkward by using: If I were **to have money**.

Comment: @Lambie so basically you are saying that the grammar is fine here?

Comment: Most simply, “If I were to have money” is so theoretical that outside imaginary constructs, it has no meaning. Would you like to challenge that?

Comment: Something can be grammatical and still be very heavy or odd sounding. I would never say those. They only would be used in a context where there is a discussion about asking the interlocutor to imagine a situation.  "So, you won't marry me because you don't love me at all.  But what if I were somehow to get a lot of money, then, would you consider it?" In other words, they can be used for setting a scenario that is most unlikely. [as Fumble Fingers has already mentioned.]

Comment: Ok so I may use it for unrealistic scenarios...

Comment: If you use 'If I were to have money' instead of 'If I had some money / the money / any money' in an essay, I'd mark it wrong. 'If I were to' requires an action (possibly inchoative: 'If I were to come into some money') verb not a stative one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can you give an action verb example

Comment: Your example 2 works.

Comment: _If I were to have some some ham, I would have ham and eggs - if I had some eggs._